# How to delete invalid token?

Tags: 7, tokens

After a recent migration from D6 to D7 some of the product descriptions made in the body of certain content types contains technical data like this:

```
[0...+70°C: ±0,2°C]
```

This is interpreted as tokens by the site and I get this message when I try to edit the content and then save the changes:

```
The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [0...+70°C: ±0,2°C]
```

How can I get around this, since it is not possible to save changes? I have tried to change the value directly in the database and then clear all cache, but the problem is still the same.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what the problem was. It was the Metatag module that copied the content in the body (using tokens) and used it as metatag description text. So by simply editing the metatag description field I got rid of the problem.